# Ukrainian keyboard layout on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard-layout

There is no option for keyboard layout Ukrainian language in Ubuntu 22.04. Russian layout does not cover such request.

Comment: Yes there is. If you need help to select it, please edit your question and let us know what you tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Settings
2. Go to Keyboard
3. Click the + under Input Sources:

[image: Keyboard Menu]

4. Click this Vertical ellipses thing at the bottom of the list:

[image: Adding an input source]

5. Scroll to the bottom of the list and click Other:

[image: Adding an input source 2]

6. Search for Ukrainian, use the appropriate layout:

[image: Ukrainian layouts.]

Answer (score 0):

In the "Ubuntu Settings" window, go to the "Keyboard" section.
There, under the "input sources" table, you'll see a "manage installed languages" button. Click on it to bring up a new window. (note it might ask for an update, but I guess it's optional at this stage as no change has been made yet)
There, you'll be able to "add/remove languages" through the dedicated button. You'll find Ukrainian in the list.
Validate all your changes, accept update request if needed, and it *should* be okay.
Hope that helps...

Comment: That's an answer to another question but the one asked above. Adding a language that way will allow you to select that language as the display language and/or select it for regional formats. But that's unrelated to keyboard layout for typing the language.

Comment: My bad... Let me correct myself. In the "Ubuntu Settings" window, go to the "Region and Language" section. There, click on the "+" sign inside the "input sources". If Ukrainian isn't in the list that appears, click on the "three vertical dots" button to show more languages. If Ukrainian still isn't in the list, click on "other" (all the way down the list). Patiently wait 10-15 seconds (especially if you're running on a potato PC like I do right now) and a more complete list will show up with a search field. I, for instance, have 7 Ukrainian options (8 with the "Russian (Ukraine)")

Comment: That's an improvement indeed. ;) It looks like you are on Ubuntu 20.04, though, while the OP asked about 22.04. In the latter you start with *Keyboard* rather than *Region and Language*. I made that change to your answer.

Comment: Oopsie, I forgot to upgrade to Jamie! Thanks for pointing it out, I'm now up-to-date ;)